# How to save sweet alert prompt in a js variable

Tags: sweetalert

I have this code

```
var pass = prompt("Please enter your password:", "");
```

I want to make this prompt through Sweet Alert and save it in variable pass. So far I have done this but I don't know how to save it in a variable.

```
swal({
content: {
element: "input",
attributes: {
 placeholder: "Type your password",
  type: "password",
},
},
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
var pass = null;

swal({
    content: {
        element: "input",
        attributes: {
            placeholder: "Type your password",
            type: "password",
        }
    }
})
.then(function(value) {
    pass = value;
});
```

Comment: It assigns value to pass just in the function. outside when I try to alert it to find out if the value has been passed correctly, It shows empty

Comment: You need to read about promises. You also need to know the difference between async and sync. https://jsfiddle.net/7qx8wkpd/6/